# After change to developer mode got a issue in "Magezon_PageBuilderIconBox/css/styles.less"

Tags: magento2.4

main.CRITICAL: Compilation from source: LESS file is empty: frontend/_view/en_US/Magezon_PageBuilderIconBox/css/styles.less

Answer (score 0):

please specify the magento version that you are using.

Steps to Reproduces

- Run command: PHP `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`
- Flush the cache
- Debug the preference of your Magezon_PageBuilderIconBox/css/styles.less
- Check the error log-in *exception.log* recorded
- Put your CSS file in your theme and check the URL from where it's generating.